# Lua errorPANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (attempt to call a nil value)

Tags: c++, lua

this is the code, when execute get the error:"PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (attempt to call a nil value)"

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern "C"{
#include "lua.h"
#include "lualib.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"
};

lua_State *L;
int luaAdd(int x, int y)
{
int sum;
lua_getglobal(L, "add");
lua_pushnumber(L, x);
lua_pushnumber(L, y);
lua_call(L, 2, 1);
sum = (int)lua_tonumber(L, -1);
lua_pop(L, 1);
return sum;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int sum = 0;
  L = lua_open();
  luaL_openlibs(L);
  luaL_dofile(L, "add.lua");
  sum = luaAdd(10, 15);
  printf("The sum is %d\n", sum);
  lua_close(L);

  return 0;
}
```

add.lua

```
function add(x, y) do
  return x + y
end
end
```

can you tell me ,where am i wrong.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get an error when compiling the file? For example, does Lua actually *find* `add.lua` correctly?

Comment: I got the answer,you cannot image,i put the add.lua in an incorrect directory, i put it in a directory where the cpp file is, when i put it in the project directory ,then it works.
thankyou @lhf and Nicol Bolas.

Answer (score 1):

You know what, I had the same problem and solved it by realizing that when running something from codeblocks, **it didn't have the same working directory as the place on disk where the executable is**. When running from cmd to make sure I had the right working directory, **making sure that my c++ program really could find the lua file, and** validating my lua code for errors at [ideone](http://ideone.com/), I was able to run successfully. Now, your problem might be something else, but try these steps at least and let us know how it went.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your filename is *add.lua*,not *lua.add*.Because I once mistaken the name and the error appered was same with yours.After I changed it correctly,it worked.And don't forget to put it in the the same directory with your executable file.